# FullCalendar Unique Custom Weekly View

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

Is it possible to build a weekly view from scratch like the picture link - using the Json structure below?

```
var nestedEvents = {
    "ABC": [
        { 
            title: 'Test-1',
            startDate: moment,
            endDate: moment,
            "allDay": true
        },{ 
            title: 'Test-2',
            startTime: moment,
            endTime: moment,
            "allDay": true
        }
    ],
    "DEF": [
        { 
            title: 'Test-3',
            startTime: moment,
            endTime: moment,
            "allDay": true
        }
    ]
};
```

[image]

Comment: So basically is there a legitimate way to do row grouping using the JSON structure? Kind of like in ui-grid but simpler http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the help of the format functions of [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment(startDate).format('w') //returns the weeknumber (from 1 to 53)  
moment(startDate).format('d') //returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6)
```

First you would have to create an object where you can store your events ordered by week.

Then you would have to loop over your events and push each event to this object using the corresponding week and day index of your event:

```
for(var i=0; i<events.length; i++){
    var weekIndex = moment(startDate).format('w')-1; 
    var dayIndex = moment(startDate).format('d');

    calendar.weeks[weekIndex].days[dayIndex].events.push(events[i]);
}
```

The result (for one year) would have to look something like this:

```
var calendar = {

"weeks": [
  {
     "weekNumber": 0,
     "days": [
        {
           "dayNumber": 0,
           "events": [
              {
                 "title": "Test-1",
                 "startDate": moment,
                 "endDate": moment
                 "allDay": true
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "dayNumber": 1,
           "events": [
              {
                 "eventNumber": 0,
                 "title": "Test-2",
                 "startDate": moment,
                 "endDate": moment,
                 "allDay": true
              },
              {
                 "eventNumber": 1
              },
              {}
           ]
        },
        {
           "dayNumber": 2
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "weekNumber": 1
  },
  {
     "weekNumber": 2
  },
  {}
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That would give me the structure to collect the events from a nested structure. However, the fullcalendar JavaScript plugin/library (I am using) is designed to take in a flat structure. My issue is with rendering this nested structure with multiple headers (like the picture). https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/dist/fullcalendar.js. It looks like there's first a skeleton and then events are inserted into it based on dates. Seems like 'renderHtml' and 'headerInto' methods are generating the skeleton. This nested structure seems completely different paradigm.